# Showing that a group has infinite order

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group such that for all $g \in G$ and for all positive integers $k$, there exists some $h \in G$ such that $h^k = g$.

Now, I would like to show that the group is either the trivial group, or of infinite size. The trivial case is straightforward, but I am having trouble proving the infinite cardinality.

I start by supposing that $G$ has finite cardinality with $|G| = m>1$ where $m$ is some integer. I now pick an abitrary $g$ and $k=m+1$, and the corresponding $h$ so that we have $h^k=g$.

If I am on the right track, I'm lost as to where to go to from here. If I am not on the right track, well then I am quite lost!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try instead $k=m$

Comment: One easy way to go is to use the fact that we know exactly what the finite abelian groups are, and that it is easy to verify that a product of cyclic groups is not divisible (the name of your property).

Comment: Hint: assuming that $a>1$ is the largest order of any element of $G$, choose such an element $g$ and set $k=a$. This is similar to @user8268's suggestion, but should actually prove the stronger statement that $G$ has elements of arbitrarily large order, and without the abelian assumption.

Comment: @GregMartin, is this to direct me to find that the element $g$ has infinite order, and thus the group $G$ does too? In any case, I am still a little bit lost as to how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: @TopherNoms You cannot prove that the group has an element of infinite order, because it might not be true. But if not then it must have elements of arbitrarily large finite order. You could argue by contradiction. Choose $g \in G$ such that $g$ has the largest possible order that is a prime power $p^k$. Now choose $h \in G$ with $h^p=g$. Then $h$ has order $p^{k+1}$, contradiction.

Comment: @CaptainLama I think this might be the most elegant way to go about it, I will see how I go!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is finite. Let $g \in G$ be arbitrary. Then there exists some $h \in G$ such that $h^{\lvert G \rvert} = g$. But $h^{\lvert G \rvert} = e$ by Lagrange's theorem! Since $g$ was arbitary, we conclude that $G = \{e\}$ is trivial.

Comment: That wins the prize (whch you have to share with Hagen von Eitzen) for the simplest solution!

Comment: I like this answer

Comment: So, abelianity assumption in the OP is not necessary, is it?

Comment: Correct, it is not! I think the assumption is there because abelian groups with this property (usually called "divisible abelian groups") are very important in the theory of abelian groups (they are the injective objects in the category of abelian groups).

Answer (score 5):

If $m:=|G|$ is finite, then $h^m=e$ for all $h\in G$. So with $k=m$ (not $m+1$), we conclude from the existence of $h$ with $h^k=g$ that $g=e$.

Comment: Welp, jinx! Apologies, I didn't mean to scoop you.

Answer (score 2):

If $m:=|G|$ is finite, then $h^m=e$ for all $h\in G$. So with $k=m$ (not $m+1$), we conclude from the existence of $h$ with $h^k=g$ that $g=e$ (and so $m=1$).

---

Alternative approach:
Suppose $G$ is not trivial and let $1\ne a\in G$. If $a$ has inifnite order, $G$ is infintei and we are done. So assume $a^m=1$ for some $m>1$. Then $x\mapsto x^m$ is not injective, but by assumption is surjective. This is possible only for infinite sets.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is not the trivial group, take $g\in G\setminus\{e_G\}$. There is some $h_1\in G$ such that $h_1^{\,2}=g$ and there is some $h_2\in G$ such that $h_2^{\,3}=g$. But then $h_1\ne h_2$, since this would imply that $h_1^{\,2}=h_1^{\,3}$, which in turn would imply that $h_1=e_G$, which is impossible, since $g\ne e_G$. Now, take $h_3\in G$ such that $h_3^{\,7}=g$. Then $7\equiv1\pmod2$ and $7\equiv1\pmod3$. So, by the same argument as before, $h_3\ne h_1$ and $h_3\ne h_2$. And so on…

Comment: I think there are substantially simpler solutions.